# remove white space in active directory samaccount name with powershell from csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am very new to powershell and am running into a road block I can not figure out. I have a CSV with a list of 380 user accounts with one white space behind their samaccount name.  This is on a Windows 2003 server that has PSv2 and Quest.Activeroles.admanagement
This is what I have so far

`add-pssnapin quest.activeroles.admanagement

get-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement

Import-Csv "C:\Documents and Settings\%user%\Desktop\withspaces2.csv" | 
ForEach{
Set-QADUser $_.sAMAccountName.Replace(' ',"").Replace("\t","")
}`

It is removing the white space for the first user but doing nothing to the others here is what the Errors looks like.

```
Name                           Type            DN
```

----                           ----            --
ABPR                           user            CN=ABPR,CN=Users,DC=DRIVERS,DC=...

ADDJ                           user            CN=ADDJ,CN=Users,DC=DRIVERS,DC=...
Set-QADUser : Ambiguous identity: ALLMA.

At line:3 char:12

- Set-QADUser <<<<  $_.sAMAccountName.Replace(' ',"").Replace("\t","")

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-QADUser], IdentityException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.BusinessLogi 
    c.IdentityException,Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Powershell.Cmdlets
    .SetUserCmdlet

ALLR                           user            CN=ALLR,CN=Users,DC=DRIVERS,DC=...

ALLS                           user            CN=ALLS,CN=Users,DC=DRIVERS,DC=...

Set-QADUser : Ambiguous identity: AMAB.

At line:3 char:12

- Set-QADUser <<<<  $_.sAMAccountName.Replace(' ',"").Replace("\t","")

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-QADUser], IdentityException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.BusinessLogi 
    c.IdentityException,Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Powershell.Cmdlets
    .SetUserCmdlet

Answer (score 1):

Try looking into .Trim() rather than replace

Example:

```
import-csv "mycsv" | foreach-object {get-qaduser -sAMAccountName $_.sAMAccountName | set qaduser -sAMAccountName $_.sAMAccountName.Trim()}
```

I haven't tested but it's worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the formatting, this is just to demonstrate that String.Trim() removes the last blank space from your string and exports it to another CSV to verify.

```
$array = @()
Foreach ($item in Import-Csv 'C:\CSVFileName')
{
    $obj = New-Object PsObject
    $obj | Add-Member -Name samAccountName -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $item.samAccountName.Trim() #Value is the name of the column with your samAccountNames
    $array += $obj
}
$array | Export-Csv C:\NewCSVFile.Csv -NoTypeInformation
```